# Use a Mysqi value as a PHP Array Delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out how I can take fields from a mysql database using Mysqli and put them into a PHP Array... but I want to use one of the fields as the key delimiter for the multidimensional array.

For Example, here's what I might have in the database:

**ID      Name      Price      Available**
1       8x10        12.00      Y
2       5x7          13.00      Y
3       11x14      14.00      N

And if I were to put that into an array like this:

```
   $OSQL = "SELECT * FROM Prices"; $PriceList=array(); 
   $OSQL = mysqli_query($dbc,$OSQL);
    while ($RW = mysqli_fetch_assoc($OSQL)) { $PriceList[]=$RW; }
```

I would get this:

```
Array    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => 8x10
            [Price] => 12.00
            [Active] => Y
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Name] => 5x7
            [Price] => 13.00
            [Active] => Y
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [Name] => 11x14
            [Price] => 14.00
            [Active] => N
        )
```

But I'd like to format it like this with the NAME as the multidimensional array key name instead of 0, 1, and 2:

```
    Array    (
    [8x10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => 8x10
            [Price] => 12.00
            [Active] => Y
        )    
    [5x7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [Name] => 5x7
            [Price] => 13.00
            [Active] => Y
        )    
    [11x14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [Name] => 11x14
            [Price] => 14.00
            [Active] => N
        )
```

I realize I could always use the while ($RW = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...)) loop to reorganize the array, but I was curious if there's a quick solution at the time of making the array or even getting it from the database. Is there an easier way that's right in front of my nose and I'm missing it? Thanks!

Comment: `$PriceList[$RW['Name']]=$RW;`

Comment: You've already answered your own question, you must loop through the array and rebuild it yourself.

Comment: @Ja͢ck had the solution, that works perfect! thanks! I can't accept your answer because it was a comment, but if you want to repost it as an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it as the answer.